# JSON payload from Heroku

Tags: ruby, json, heroku

When I get a JSON payload from my Rails heroku site (this is a basic simple test site made with the 'generate scaffold' command), I get something like this:

```
[
{"client":
    {"name":"Fred Flintstone",
    "id":3,
    "room":"333",
    },
{"client":
    {"name":"Wilma Flintstone",
    "id":4,
    "room":"334",
    }
}
```

]

I would really like to get something more KVC compliant, like this:

```
{"clients":
[
{"client":
    {"name":"Fred Flintstone",
    "id":3,
    "room":"333",
    },
{"client":
    {"name":"Wilma Flintstone",
    "id":4,
    "room":"334",
    }
}
]
```

}

Does anyone know how to do this?  Is there some code on the Ruby side or on Heroku's side that will give me this format?

Kurt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller, instead of

```
render :json => @clients
```

do

```
render :json => {@clients.first.class.name.underscore.pluralize => @clients}
```

or

```
render :json => {@clients.first.class.table_name => @clients}
```

This doesn't have anything to do with heroku.

You can turn on/off whether or not the resulting object will have the name of the object as a top level key using:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true
```

But as far as I know, there is no configuration option to do what you are suggesting.

See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json

Another option, if you wish to do this in more than one controller, is to move this behavior to a helper and use that.  The logic presented above will work regardless of the model in question.

ie:

```
def kvcize(array)
  {array.first.class.table_name => array}
end
```

then

```
render :json => kvcize(@clients)
```

Comment: Thank you Dan. I tried both of your render suggestions, and they work well.  The 'ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true' did not work for me.  Since this is a test project, I didn't try the helper, but I'm sure that would work as well.  Thank you for such a complete answer.

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true`  turns on/off the singular "client" : key, not the plural one you are requesting.